# Symmetric encryption on a network stream (TCP Socket)

Tags: c#, encryption, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream

I am working on simple program which acts as proxy between a client and HTTP proxy server , i have no issue in exchanging data from client to proxy and back when using simple Stream.copytoasync function. I have tried to modify the function to add simple symmetric encryption using the following code:

**For encryption (Client end, copies from client stream to server stream):**

```
public static async Task CopyEncrypt(this Stream source, Stream destination,string encryption_key, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken), int bufferSize = 0x1000)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead;            
            while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken)) > 0)
            {
               
                byte[] eca = Encrypt(buffer, encryption_key); 
                await destination.WriteAsync(eca, 0, eca.Length, cancellationToken);
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();                
            }
        }
```

**For Decryption (Server end, takes data sent by client , and forwards it to http proxy):**

```
public static async Task CopyDecrypt(this Stream source, Stream destination,string aeskey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken), int bufferSize = 0x1000)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead;            
            while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken)) > 0)
            {

                byte[] eca = Decrypt(buffer, aeskey);
                await destination.WriteAsync(eca, 0, eca.Length, cancellationToken);
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }
```

I have tried multiple Encrypt/Decrypt functions , including AES , TripleDES, Rijndael. Whenever using these with Padding i usually get the following error while decryption (Using same padding for Encryption and Decryption) :

`Padding is invalid and cannot be removed`

When using without any padding the data gets decrypted but seems like the data is not transmitted properly/completely as the process through the HTTP proxy fails after sending the headers.

**Whereas the process works fine with the following functions without the encryption:**

**For Encryption:**

```
public static async Task CopyEncrypt(this Stream source, Stream destination,string encryption_key, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken), int bufferSize = 0x1000)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken)) > 0)
            {

                
                await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cancellationToken);
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            }
        }
```

**For Decryption:**

```
public static async Task CopyDecrypt(this Stream source, Stream destination,string aeskey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken), int bufferSize = 0x1000)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken)) > 0)
            {

                await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cancellationToken);
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of your `Encrypt`/`Decrypt` functions leads me to believe that they are trying to treat each buffer as a complete message. This means any padding would be added to each buffer.

When you're working with streams, you need to encrypt/decrypt as a stream. That way, any padding will only be at the very end of the stream.

The easiest way to do this is to use `CryptoStream` and then you can just copy the crypto stream just like a regular stream.